# Can anybody help me identify this font I've search everywhere

Tags: font-identification

Been looking for this font every where can't seem to find it I'm not sure when this font comes from and what font pack family it originates thank you for anyone's help.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - *Please* look through **[tour]** to get a sense of our community – who we are and what we’re about. *Then* look over **[ask]** and **[answer]** a question to see what makes a good query here, *and* how best to frame it. We ***do*** ask that your question shows some *effort*: tell us what you already know and understood; show us what you tried and failed; document what you found when searching the Internet or manual. We have specific requirements for Font ID questions: https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1083 please edit your post to meet them - thanks!

Comment: Reminds me of the lettering of Vaughn Bode.

Answer (score 4):

That's **not** a "font"

The Os and Gs are different. It is hand drawn type.

Comment: Scott is correct, of course - but there is a reasonably close facsimile: https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/gatf/leibix/outline-condensed-regular/

Answer (score 0):

See font Disko, marketed by Blue Vinyl, free for personal usage(see NOTE1):

[image]

As already said by others, your image is a drawing. "Os and Gs are different" is probably more true than member  Scott has intended. A text with font Disko can have been used only as a loose basis for a drawing.

How loose? One comment says that if there's some resemblance, it can be only a coincidence. One test:

[image]

I distorted text BAR by stretching horizontally and vertically the bounding boxes of B, A and R until the outlines matched with questioner's image. Then also the holes  of the letters fitted. I did no rotation nor warping.

The letters are colored to blue. In the top they are placed on the image, their blending mode=Screen. In the bottom they are moved aside and have blending mode = normal.

I do not believe that simultaneously matching exteriors and interiors got by stretching are a random coincidence. G and O have got new simpler outlines, but the rest resemble too much stretched Disko glyphs.

Comment: Is that font not simply a coincidental resemblance to the drawing in the question? I can see multiple differences, especially on G. "That's Disko" in your answer simply is not correct right?

Comment: There's something added about so called coincidence.